# add current position+1 or -1 dict value to dict python

Tags: python-3.x

for example:
s = 'abc'
number = 1

I want to write a function that return a dict like {'a': {'a', 'b'}, 'b': {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'c': {'b', 'c'}}

number determine how many adjacent letters next to the current key.

```js
def test(s : str, num : int) -> {str:{str}}:
    dict = {}
    for word in s:
        dict[word] = word
    return dict
```

i can only write one return the same key and value. any suggestions?

Comment: what if you have `abcabc`?

Comment: it will return {'a': {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'b': {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'c': {'a', 'b', 'c'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
>>> s='abc'
>>> n=1
>>> {c:{e for e in[s[i-n:i],c,s[i+1:i+1+n]] if e} for i, c in enumerate(s)}
{'a': {'a', 'b'}, 'b': {'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'c': {'b', 'c'}}
```